LEDs not working after switching from Red to White
I replaced the red SMD LEDs from my car's center console control unit (Audi A4 B8 2013). First the LEDs lit up and everything was fine. After a few seconds they all shut down and just flicker (barely visible). The buttons on the board also don't work anymore in this state, but the reset button does. I know this board communicates via RX/TX pin with the radio unit.
I successfully switched the LEDs in every other part on the car, but this seems to be far more complicated.
I am not new to electronics, have designed PCBs myself, made sure the solder joints are all solid etc... But that many ICs and transistors/resistors are just confusing. Its a multi-layer board.
I just want to find out how to make the white LEDs work. Any help would be gladly appreciated (would even pay, to finally understand it).
Kind regards :)

Front-side. Excuse the mess! Bridged solder blobs were there to temporarely test something (usually places for the red/now white leds). The two leds in the middle must not be changed as they serve the purpose to recognize the turning of the main knob.

Back-side

Well how does the circuit work then? That question is to assess if it is even possible to change red LEDs to white LEDs. They have completely different voltage and could be rated for completely different amount of current and it may be impossible to just swap the LEDs without changing the circuitry that powers them. That's basically the equivalent of living in a 110V country and trying to switch 110V appliances to 220V appliances and expecting them to work at 110V.

If the buttons stopped working then probably you shorted or damaged something. Normally white LEDs placed in a circuit designed for red would draw significantly less current and perhaps not be bright enough, but you would not expect that to prevent other functions on the board from working.

Well thanks but no its not shorted. When i resolder the red LEDs it works again

White LED needs more current. You have to modify the resistor values accordingly.

@liaifat85 No they really don't need more current. They need more voltage, and circuits intended for red LEDs may not have enough voltage for white LEDs even if you used zero ohm resistor. And, the driving circuit is unknown, it is unlikely that it would just be a simple LED+resistor in a lightng application, compare with LED strips driven with tens of volts with constant current driver.

Thanks for correcting me. I meant to say higher forward voltage.

I just realized that the original leds were red low current leds with a cf of 2mA. The whites are 20mA. According to my calculations the circuit resistance therefore would have to be 1/10 of the original resistance. If I can get my hands on some low currwnt white leds it should work, even with the the higher vf i think

The current rating on an LED is the maximum current you can supply, so a 20 mA LED is a good choice for running with a 2mA current.  A 2 mA current LED would not be a good choice, since you'd be close to its maximum.

No that is not the case. I said cf (Forward current) 2mA. This is NOT the surge current or max current of the led. 20mA forward current or 2mA cF would be a difference of a couple thousand ohms circuit resistance in this example, so it would be important to get it right

@TJCDE If the rated forward current of the old LEDs is 2 mA, then it is safe to replace them with a 20mA rated LED. Since the new rating is 10x higher than the old, everything will work.  Replacing them with LEDs rated for 1/10th as much current is not a sensible thing to do, so don't waste your time going down that route.  Figure out what the underlying problem is.

Needs an input capacitor, but an SMD Joule-Thief might work. This was purchased from Amazon in 2017 but is not currently available. Does anyone know what problems there might be (and how to sidestep them, if possible).

Many automotive LED systems have a feature called 'Functional Safety' -- basically they detect faults and ultimately drive an indicator light. If these LEDs are part of that system, then the circuits probably detect the VF (forward voltage) of the LED and if it is 'abnormal' (which a white could be if replacing a red one), the driver may consider it failed and go into a test/retry loop.

i also thought the white leds may consume a lot more current than the red ones, and the chip detects it or something like that. because they worked, then stopped and never worked since. Since voltage and current have a direct relationship.

@TJCDE No, voltage and current are not directly related with semiconductors. Especially LEDs are not linear.
